# python database API encoding

Tags: python, linux, utf-8, cubrid

I'm trying to get UTF-8 data from CUBRID using python DB API like followings.

```
con = CUBRIDdb.connect("CUBRID:localhost:30000:yoondb:::","public");

cur = con.cursor();

qry = "select * from log";

cur.execute(qry)

print cur.fetchall()
```

and i wrote down python xxx.py in linux command line to execute it.

but it only shows code like below.

```
\uac80\uc0c9\uc5b4\uc5d0 \\r
```

i set utf-8 encoding when i installed CUBRID and i'm using Linux with LANG=ko_KR.utf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's working correctly! The Unicode characters U+AC80, U+C0C9, U+C5B4, U+C5D0 make up the string "검색어에".

Keep in mind that the `fetchall()` method on a Cursor object returns a list of rows. You'll need to extract individual rows and columns from that list to work with them.

Comment: thank you i just resolved problem by doing ` print a.encode('utf-8')`